# Python - how to run 2 scripts in parallel

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I used to have one script which has 2 functions:

1: collecting images
2: processing images

And I set a schedule to let my computer keep repeating the job everyday/every period. However I found it's not efficient since processing sometimes takes long time and I want to keep collecting images.

So I am wondering if I can split two functions into two scripts. the first script will keep collecting images periodically and the second script will process the collected images (say maybe it takes 2 days to process and by the next time, the computer will process images collected from previous 2 days).

Since I have some command line arguments for example:

```
python test.py --start-time 20:00
```

I don't know how to properly call/achieve that. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not run both methods in seperate threads within the same script? Make the 'collecting' function append to a list when it completes a successful 'collection' and have the 'processing' function continuously poll the list and see if there is work to do

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: It sounds to me like you would want to use multiple thread/processes. The first question you have to consider is, if you want to achieve that parallelisation from within your script or if you want to leverage the OS scheduler for that. I would probably go with multi-threading within python, as @tehjoker suggested.

Comment: If you work on Linux, you can set a cronjob.

Comment: I think the best strategy kind of depends on if your images are collected and/or processed one by one or in batches. What I mean with that is, does the processing step depend on more than one image at the time or not.

Comment: After further consideration I have come to think, that perhaps the easiest solution would be two separate scripts as you yourself suggested. One downloads/collects the images into a specific folder and the other checks if there are any images in said folder and if so processes them and moves them somewhere else. This should be easier to implement, especially if one is unfamiliar with python multithreading and the like.

Comment: @tehjoker Thanks for the solution! I am gonna try the multithreading and see how it goes

Comment: @PeterE Thank you! I am not familiar with multithreading but I am gonna try both. Do you know if I can call two scripts in another script?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thx for the tips yet I am using windows :P

Comment: @AustinChen try [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Comment: @PeterE Thank you! but I realized that I want my collector can keep running whenever my processor is running or not. Simply call two scripts still has a sequence..